# Angular-NVD3 Chart not Rendering

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

Title says it all: the chart simply doesn't render. I am trying to implement the example given [here](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/quickstart).

All of the scripts and stylesheets are accessible (no 404's). I'm sure this is something glaringly obvious, but I can't quite see what it is. I'm using Google Chrome V49, and don't have a problem with charts on other websites.

Here is the page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Monitoring - Integration Hub</title>
        <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Integration Hub</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/Monitoring">Monitoring</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Settings">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Credentials">Credentials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Logs">Logs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Mappings">Mappings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, User!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <div ng-app="monitoringApp">
                <h2>Monitoring</h2>
                <p>
                    The information presented on this page has a sample resolution of 5 seconds.
                </p>
                <div ng-controller='OverviewCtrl'>
                    <nvd3 options='options' data='data'></nvd3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; Some Org, 2016.</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/nv.d3.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/Apps/monitoring-app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here are the contents of monitoring-app.js:

```
var settingsApp = angular.module('monitoringApp', []);
settingsApp.controller('OverviewCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'discreteBarChart',
            height: 450,
            margin: {
                top: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 60,
                left: 55
            },
            x: function (d) { return d.label; },
            y: function (d) { return d.value; },
            showValues: true,
            valueFormat: function (d) {
                return d3.format(',.4f')(d);
            },
            transitionDuration: 500,
            xAxis: {
                axisLabel: 'X Axis'
            },
            yAxis: {
                axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
                axisLabelDistance: 30
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.data = [{
        key: "Cumulative Return",
        values: [
            { "label": "A", "value": -29.765957771107 },
            { "label": "B", "value": 0 },
            { "label": "C", "value": 32.807804682612 },
            { "label": "D", "value": 196.45946739256 },
            { "label": "E", "value": 0.19434030906893 },
            { "label": "F", "value": -98.079782601442 },
            { "label": "G", "value": -13.925743130903 },
            { "label": "H", "value": -5.1387322875705 }
        ]
    }];
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Problem was the following line:

```
var settingsApp = angular.module('monitoringApp', []);
```

Should have been:

```
var settingsApp = angular.module('monitoringApp', ['nvd3']);
```

Hopefully this helps others who encounter this very subtle error.